# Save data from SWXMLHash

Tags: arrays, swift, swxmlhash

I got this set of response data:

```
<delivery_zones>
                <zone>3</zone>
                <zone_name>Within Klang Valley</zone_name>
        </delivery_zones>
<delivery_zones>
                <zone>3</zone>
                <zone_name>Within Klang Valley</zone_name>
        </delivery_zones>
<delivery_zones>
                <zone>3</zone>
                <zone_name>Within Klang Valley</zone_name>
        </delivery_zones>
<delivery_zones>
                <zone>3</zone>
                <zone_name>Within Klang Valley</zone_name>
                <zone>1</zone>
                <zone_name>East Malaysia</zone_name>
                <zone>2</zone>
                <zone_name>Outside Klang Valley</zone_name>
</delivery_zones>
```

which i wanted to save and display it, here is my code:

```
for elem3 in elem["delivery_zones"]{
```

//but is not working, the apps getting crash and this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
         self.zone.append(elem3["zone"].element!.text!)     

 }
```

Comment: which xml parser are you using?

Comment: Is that the exact response you are receiving as you have shown above, nothing more than that? There should be a root element. And some more code.

Comment: @Mr.UB yes, this is the exact response that i get, but i cant save it inside array

Comment: its because elem["delivery_zones"] gives only 1 object here you've to put delivery_zones inside a root object so that it can be parsed as an array

Comment: I checked that the response format is wrong, there should be one root node covering all other nodes i.e your response.